# vuejs undefined is not an object in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I'm receiving a response from an api with data and would like to show the results with vuejs in a table. This works fine, until some parameters a missing.

So how can I skip the whole row in v-for, when e.g this `{{ sp . article_data . desc_de }}` is undefined?
Or how can I show the results except the values which are empty / null?

Backgrund information: When there's a conflict with incomplete data, then the `sp.article` object is completely missing. Parameters like `{{ sp . name }}` or `{{ sp . type }}` are always available.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possibilities:

- Use v-if to display data conditionally
- filter the unwanted rows in a computed property
- use optional chaining to cope with missing data

Answer (score 0):

As you said, In some cases whole `article` object will be missing. In this case you can use [`Optional chaining (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

In below Demo, `article` object is missing from the 4th object and for `undefined`/`null` values, It is showing an empty cell.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    spData: [{
        id: 1,
      name: 'Alpha',
      type: 'Type 1',
      article: {
        desc_de: 'abc'
      }
    }, {
        id: 2,
      name: 'Beta',
      type: 'Type 2',
      article: {
        desc_de: undefined
      }
    }, {
        id: 3,
      name: 'Gamma',
      type: 'Type 3',
      article: {
        desc_de: 'def'
      }
    }, {
        id: 4,
      name: 'Delta',
      type: 'Type 4'
    }] 
  }
})
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Article</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="sp in spData" :key="sp.id">
       <td>{{ sp.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ sp.type }}</td>
       <td>{{ sp.article?.desc_de }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Now, If you want to remove whole row if any of the column value is empty. Then, you can achieve that by simply applying the [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method while iterating.

```
v-for="sp in spData.filter(x => x.article && x.article.desc_de)"
```

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    spData: [{
        id: 1,
      name: 'Alpha',
      type: 'Type 1',
      article: {
        desc_de: 'abc'
      }
    }, {
        id: 2,
      name: 'Beta',
      type: 'Type 2',
      article: {
        desc_de: undefined
      }
    }, {
        id: 3,
      name: 'Gamma',
      type: 'Type 3',
      article: {
        desc_de: 'def'
      }
    }, {
        id: 4,
      name: 'Delta',
      type: 'Type 4'
    }] 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Article</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="sp in spData.filter(x => x.article && x.article.desc_de)" :key="sp.id">
       <td>{{ sp.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ sp.type }}</td>
       <td>{{ sp.article?.desc_de }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```